# split and flatten tuple of tuples

Tags: python, list, split, flatten

What is the best way to split and flatten the tuple of tuples below?

I have this tuple of tuples:

```
(('aaaa_BBB_wacker*  cccc',), ('aaaa_BBB_tttt*',), ('aaaa_BBB2_wacker,aaaa_BBB',), ('BBB_ffff',), ('aaaa_BBB2MM*\r\naaaa_BBB_cccc2MM*',), ('BBBMM\\r\\nBBB2MM BBB',), ('aaaa_BBB_cccc2MM_tttt',), ('aaaa_BBB_tttt, aaaa_BBB',))
```

I need to:
split by \n\, \r\, \n\, \r\, ",", " "

and flatten it. So the end result should look like this:

```
['aaaa_BBB_wacker*','cccc', 'aaaa_BBB_tttt*','aaaa_BBB2_wacker','aaaa_BBB','BBB_ffff','aaaa_BBB2MM*','naaaa_BBB_cccc2MM*','BBBMM','BBB2MM BBB','aaaa_BBB_cccc2MM_tttt','aaaa_BBB_tttt', 'aaaa_BBB']
```

I tried the following and it eventually completes the job but I have to repeat it multiple times for each pattern.

```
patterns = [[i.split('\\r') for i in patterns]]
patterns = [item for sublist in patterns for item in sublist]
patterns = [item for sublist in patterns for item in sublist]
patterns = [[i.split('\\n') for i in patterns]]
```

Comment: If your solution works how do you want it to be different?  Usually the best way to do something is one that works.

Comment: in addition to the answers posted, for the flattening part, see `itertools.chain.from_iterable`...

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
tups = (('aaaa_BBB_wacker*  cccc',), ('aaaa_BBB_tttt*',), 
    ('aaaa_BBB2_wacker,aaaa_BBB',), ('BBB_ffff',), 
    ('aaaa_BBB2MM*\r\naaaa_BBB_cccc2MM*',), ('BBBMM\\r\\nBBB2MM BBB',), 
    ('aaaa_BBB_cccc2MM_tttt',), ('aaaa_BBB_tttt, aaaa_BBB',))
```

Do

```
import re
delimiters = ('\r', '\n', ',', ' ', '\\r', '\\n')
pat = '(?:{})+'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters)))
result = [s for tup in tups for item in tup for s in re.split(pat, item)]
```

Notes.  Calling `re.escape` on your delimiters makes sure that they are properly escaped for your regular expression.  `|` makes them alternatives.  `?:` makes your delimiter group non-capturing so it isn't returned by `re.split`. `+` means match the previous group one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regexp to split the strings:

```
import re
re.split(r'[\n\r, ]+', s)
```

It will be easier using a loop:

```
patterns = []
for item in l:
  patterns += re.split(r'[\n\r, ]+', s)
```

Comment: Note that in addition to `'\r'` and `'\n'` he also needs to split on `'\\\r'` and `'\\\n'`.  You could just throw a backslash in that character set, but my concern would be that a lone backslash might not properly be considered a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner.. but it's not simple. You can add as many items as you want in the replace portion, just keep adding them.

```
start = (('aaaa_BBB_wacker*  cccc',), ('aaaa_BBB_tttt*',), ('aaaa_BBB2_wacker,aaaa_BBB',), ('BBB_ffff',), ('aaaa_BBB2MM*\r\naaaa_BBB_cccc2MM*',), ('BBBMM\\r\\nBBB2MM BBB',), ('aaaa_BBB_cccc2MM_tttt',), ('aaaa_BBB_tttt, aaaa_BBB',))

output = [final_item for sublist in start for item in sublist for final_item in item.replace('\\r',' ').replace('\\n',' ').split()]
```